# Cabbage Pult Missing from Almanac and My Plants in PVZ2

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

There is no Cabbage Pult in the Almanac in PVZ2. I get it on levels where it's provided automatically when the system chooses plants for me, and I've gained a lot of seed packets for it, but it's not in the almanac, so I can't raise it beyond Level 1, and I can't choose it to play on any levels when selecting my plants.

Did they remove it from being a selectable plant?

Comment: What's your progression in the worlds?

Comment: Also, do you have a screenshot?

Comment: It is still selectable, that is for sure. I watched a bunch of youtube videos and the cabbage pult is available.

Answer (score 1):

Cabbage-Pult is a selectable plant, and SHOULD be there, as you are forced to unlock it in the tutorial (I think). In the seed selection (and almanac), the first 4 plants are the tutorial plants (Sunflower, Peashooter, Wall-nut, and Potato mine) and the plant immediately after is Cabbage-Pult, it's green, and has an Egypt background. If it's not there, check every one of your plants that aren't shaded. Also, on some levels, certain plants may be banned, so check multiple levels. If you can't find it, *contact Popcap or EA* (I think there's a Troubleshooting option somewhere).